# CORS is blocking me to send images/files to my backend

Tags: node.js, angular, cors, backend

I'm a bit frustrated because I have following CORS error and I'm working on it for about 4 hours now:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/create-post/1' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
---
POST http://localhost:8080/create-post/1 net::ERR_FAILED
```

I can't find an answer for the problem.
My Service in Angular:

**Service.ts**

```
...
    uploadPicture(file) {
        return this.httpClient.post("http://localhost:8080/create-post/1", file)
                .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

    }
```

**My Component**

```
...
  onFileChanged(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file)
    this._service.uploadPicture(e.target.files[0]).subscribe((test)=>{
      console.log(test)
    })
  }
```

**My Backend**

```
...
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token');
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
  next();
});
...
app.post('/create-post/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  console.log("test")
  fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.jpg", req.body.bild, 'binary', function(err) {
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log("The file was saved!");
      return res.send('WORK PLEASE')
  });
});
```

It's not even triggering the `console.log("test")` line in the POST method, so it's already failing before it gets there.

Thanks for every answer!

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it, but you're missing the `Accept` header in your CORS setup

Comment: Have you try setting the proxy in your package.json file?  Actually just found out, you need to create, proxy.conf.json in your angular project.  https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: @WillAlexander which header do you mean exactly?

Comment: @noobius No I haven't, could you please explain me how it works?

Comment: The `Accept` header. Try adding `Accept` to your list of allowed headers in your CORS setup.

Comment: @WillAlexander I have added it but I'm still getting the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Than you set it manually. You better use the [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#readme) library.

Usage:

```js
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors()) //Add CORS middleware

app.post('/create-post/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  console.log("test")
  fs.writeFile("/tmp/test.jpg", req.body.bild, 'binary', function(err) {
    if(err)
      console.log(err);
    else
      console.log("The file was saved!");
      return res.send('WORK PLEASE')
  });
});
```

Comment: Nevermind, I had a typo and your answer worked perfectly fine! Thank you so much!